# Custom cell above other cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that gets its data from a sorted array. [A-Z]. 
How can I place a default cell to select at the top like this.

[image: example from another app] 
If a user doesn't want to click any of the other cells?
Here is my UITableViewCode below.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: nameArray, by: {String($0.prefix(1))})
        // get the keys and sort them
        let keys = groupedDictionary.keys.sorted()
        // map the sorted keys to a struct
        sections = keys.map{ Section(letter: $0, name: groupedDictionary[$0]!.sorted()) }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath()
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].names.count
        
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeNames")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeNames", for: indexPath)
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = section.names[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BBcell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        selectedHomeName = section.name[indexPath.row]
        navigationItem.title = (selectedHomeName)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sections.map{$0.letter}
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section].letter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution, in my opinion, would be to insert a new Section at the beginning of your sections variable after this line.

```
sections = keys.map{ Section(letter: $0, name: groupedDictionary[$0]!.sorted()) }
```

Something like:

```
sections.insert(Section(letter: "Default", ["All makes"]), at: 0)
```

I could have messed up the syntax a bit as I don't know your `Section`